# Detecting tablet mode in Linux on Yoga 11e?

Tags: linux, keyboard, tablet, input

I'm running Linux on a Yoga 11e (the Thinkpad model, not the Chromebook). I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to detect when the device switches to tablet mode and when it switches to laptop mode (the goal being to run a script to disable the keyboard when in tablet mode, because with an active keyboard on the bottom of a device it's easy trivial to erroneously press keys).

I've tried monitoring all the events delivered on /dev/input/event* devices and I don't see anything.  I thought maybe there would be an ACPI event, but `acpi_listen` doesn't show anything (and in fact seems to be just another view to the input subsystem).

Has anyone had any luck with a Yoga 11e?